import module from class name in vscode
as an example I have something like this:
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Category(MP_Node):
    pass

is there a way to get the suggestion in vscode for the import of the module treebeard from MP_Node like:
from treebeard.mp_tree import MP_Node--> get this line as a import suggestion from code above


i tried changing the depth and extra path in the setting and find this(VSCode: Auto import/import suggestions for Python dependencies from external libraries) but i couldn't make it work for what i wanted,i have pylance extension and work in a devcontainer mode i don't know if that's relevant,what did i miss... any suggestions ? thank you in advance

Can you elaborate on what the suggestion you want is? I can get relevant prompts when importing in vscode. Is this what you need?

actually i want it in reverse, i changed the image you send i want something 

Can you check your "python.autoComplete.addBrackets" and "python.autoComplete.extraPaths" in your settings.json? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_troubleshooting

thankyou for the response, dont have addBrackets on setting,json and the extraPath is like this:  "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [     "/py/lib/python3.12/site-packages",     "/py/lib/python3.12/site-packages/treebeard"   ],

Please note that the paths in python.autoComplete.extraPaths are absolute paths.
